# Why I cannot do self.strID=nil;?

Tags: objective-c, properties

```
self.strID=nil;
```

It pops error saying:
reason: '-[BGFacebookHandler setStrID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20525240'
*** First throw call stack:

However, I declared the property as read write privately:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString * strID;
```

The catch is it's also declared as read only publicly through protocol. Basically I am implementing that public property with a private property.

What's wrong with my approach?

Obviously I can do @synthesize, but doing so means using obsolete version of objective-c

This is a run time error. Not a compile error. The code compile just fine by the way.

Comment: are you sure strID is a property of BGFacebookHandler ?

Comment: It pass compile check. This is a run time error.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your implementation property as part of your interface or a private extension changes nothing at runtime. There must me something else missing in your code because I have the following code fragment that works fine:

```
@protocol Facebook<NSObject>
- (NSString*) strID;
@end

@interface BGFacebookHandler : NSObject<Facebook>
@property (retain) NSString * strID;
@end

@implementation BGFacebookHandler
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        BGFacebookHandler *object = [[BGFacebookHandler alloc] init];
        object.strID = @"Hello";
        NSLog(@"strID = %@",object.strID);
    }
    return 0;
}
```